# Maven: unable to create project from archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am able to make maven project using command line but when I am trying to make it from eclipse it shows me following error:

[image]

I switched my workspace and also added maven in path variable but still getting same.

please guide me what should I do to create maven project directly from eclipse.

Comment: hi can you please click the details tab which is visible on the screenshot and share the log..

Comment: @DeviKiran there is not any details simply this error appears when I click on finish button for maven project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the screenshot I can see that you are using `org.springframework:spring-context` as archetype to generate your project. Its not a valid maven archetype. That's the reason for the error message.

Comment: Yes you are right but how would I know about valid archetype? and if I want to make simple spring project then which archetype I will use??

Answer (score 0):

did you extract your eclipse folder in same drive where it download ? 
if yes than move it to another drive. I think that is the problem you are facing.
i had same problem with my eclipse juno.